# how to add a specific number of buttons created in a loop

Tags: java, swing, for-loop

i have a problem with adding a specific number of buttons from my for-loop to my JPanel, i know how to add all oof them, but i want to add only 1-10 (i havent decided yet, lets go with 10).'

this is my class where i just declare what objects i want to have.

````
    private static int cID;
    private static Deck[] card;
    static ArrayList<JButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p1;
    private JButton button;
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return cID == 0;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomDecks c = new CustomDecks();
    c.deckCreator();
}```
````

this is my for-loop where i create 420 buttons and give them names "card" + i where i is 0 - 419, yet when i try to add card0 to my panel, it fails, why?

```
private void deckCreator() {
    card = new Deck[25];
    new ArrayList<Cards> (cSet.cards);
    for(int i = 0; i < 420; i++) {
        button = new JButton();
        buttonList.add(button);
        button.setName("card" + i);
        f.add(button);
        p1.add(card0);
        }
    f.add(p1);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    f.setUndecorated(true);
}
}
}
```

Comment: You can't just add an array of objects you must add **one**  awt Component,  see overloading methods of `add()` on the docs :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can create a `JPanel` large enough to hold 420 `JButtons`.

Here's an example of a `JButton` GUI.

[[image: JButton GUI]

Generally, you create an application model and view separately.  The model is made up of one or more plain Java classes.  The view reads from the application model but doesn't update the model.

Your controller classes (`ActionListener` classes) update the application model and update / repaint the view.

This pattern is called the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.

You can see in the example code below that the model is created in the view class constructor.  Generally, you create the application model first, then you create the application view.

And here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class JButtonScrollGUI {
    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    new JButtonScrollGUI();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
    }
    
    private String[] greekAlphabet;

    public JButtonScrollGUI() {
        this.greekAlphabet = new String[] { "alpha", "beta", "gamma", "epsilon", "zeta" };
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Application");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createScrollPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createScrollPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        
        JPanel innerPanel = createButtonPanel();
        Dimension d = innerPanel.getPreferredSize();
        d.width += 50;
        d.height /= 2;
        panel.setPreferredSize(d);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(innerPanel);
        
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3, 10, 10));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            JButton button1 = new JButton("Previous " + i);
            panel.add(button1);

            JComboBox<String> selectorBox = new JComboBox<>(greekAlphabet);
            panel.add(selectorBox);

            JButton button2 = new JButton("Next " + i);
            button2.setPreferredSize(button1.getPreferredSize());
            panel.add(button2);
        }
        
        return panel;
    }
    
}
```